# Fixed inode number for files across storage devices

Tags: backup

How can we enforce that files use the same inode numbers for files across storage devices? The only way I can imagine is using `dd`, but that would require copying the whole container even if you just to add one single file.

I wanted to assign fixed ID numbers to a big batch of files. Content of files will change for sure (so md5sum won't work). ID can't be included into the file.

The purpose is a small document management system, where each incoming file gets assigned an ID, some tags/comments/status.

Nothing can be written into the file. So some template/header on it is a no-no.

So, basically each file should have a record in the form:
ID: 5683958754
Date: xxxx-xx-xx
Tags: picture, message ordoc
Action: store
Origin: client x or web-page www.sample.com ...

What's a minimalistic way of tying such meta-information with all files?

Comment: It would be useful to [understand](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/504315/edit) why you want matching inode numbers across different devices. There may be better ways to achieve whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: @roaima: adding this into the question.

Comment: Your edit does not explain **why** you want fixed ID numbers. Please add more details about your use case or about the problem you want to solve with this request.

Comment: If you want to assign fixed ID numbers, that's fine. You can (almost certainly) do that with a mapping of number to name. Explain some more - with examples - and you'll probably get some useful answers.

Answer (score 2):

> How can we enforce that files use the same inode numbers for files across storage devices?

You can't.

On the other hand, now that you've characterised your requirement,

> Each file should have a record in the form: ID: 5683958754 Date: xxxx-xx-xx Tags: picture, message ordoc Action: store Origin: client x or web-page www.sample.com ...

you could use tab-separated fields and use `grep` or `awk` to pick them out of a plain file. Much more than that and I'd suggest at the very least `sqlite`. But then we're really getting into application architecture.

I'd consider something like this

```
id <tab> date-in-seconds <tab> tag1,tag2,tag <tab> action <tab> filename <tab> filepath <tab> origin
```

You can then key by id

```
id=1234
awk -F$'\t' id="$id" '$1==id {print $6}'
```

Or by filename

```
filename='rhubarb.txt'
awk -F$'\t' key="$filename" '$5==key {print $6}'
```

Or even by date range

```
mindate=$(date --utc --date '1 mar 2019 19:00' +%s)
awk -F$'\t' key="$mindate" '$2>key {print $6}'
```

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer. Then I'll need an alternative solution.

Comment: @PierreB A document management system, such as a simple database.

Comment: @PierreB there you go. An alternative to inodes. (I've not thought very hard about it, so I'm sure there will be caveats.)